# Access certain element of listview adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an Activity with a ListView. This ListView is set with the Class `GetAllEntrysListViewAdapter`:

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ListCell cell;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_all_entry_list_view_cell, null);

        cell = new ListCell();
        cell.note = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewNote);
        cell.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewImg);
        cell.likeButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heartImage);

        convertView.setTag(cell);
    }
    else {
        cell = (ListCell)convertView.getTag();
    }

 public static class ListCell {
    private TextView note;
    private ImageView img;
    public ImageButton likeButton;
}
```

In the Activity I now want to change the Image of `likeButton` on the certain list entry that is clicked, but how can I reach this certain element? Her is what I have until now:

```
 GetAllEntrysListViewAdapter.ListCell listCell;
 listCell = new GetAllEntrysListViewAdapter.ListCell();

   getALlEntrysListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// Get the likeButton of this entry and change the Image
```

Comment: What's getALlEntrysListView?

Comment: your view thats in the onItemLongClick, its the line of the list view, so I think you should get the image and change it

ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findbyid(yourid);

then change the resource
img.setDrawable();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Replace your

```
getALlEntrysListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

@Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Get the likeButton of this entry and change the Image
}
```

with

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //first get the elements by doing like
    TextView note = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listViewNote);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewImg);
    ImageButton likeButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heartImage);

    likeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            likeButton.setBackgroundResource(R.id.icon);
        }
    });
}
```

This will be helpful ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

That part should be done in `getView()` method itself. It should work like this.

1. Set data in your Adapter
2. Display data in getView for each item
3. Once you Like any item, update data with new Like status
4. Now call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on your adapter, `getView()` will update item view accordingly.

You should read [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) first, and see some examples how it works.